# Using arrays as indexedDB keyPaths in IE 10/11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, indexeddb

I have an array as my keypath using indexedDB and it works fine with Chrome and Firefox, but when I try to add/put using IE it gives me a DataError.

```
var request = window.indexedDB.open("MyTestDatabase");

request.onsuccess = function(event) {
    var database = event.target.result;
    var transaction = database.transaction(["document"], "readwrite");
    var objectStore = transaction.objectStore("document");
    var request = objectStore.put({title: 'MyDoc', version: 0});
    request.onsuccess = function() {
        console.log('document added');
    };
    request.error = function(error) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
    };                
    transaction.oncomplete = function() {
        console.log('transaction complete');
    };
    transaction.onerror = function(error) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
    };
};

request.onupgradeneeded = function(event) {
    event.target.result.createObjectStore("document", {keyPath: ['title', 'version']});
};
```

Error Screenshot:

[image]

How can I keep my double keyPath and get it to work with IE?

Comment: Please file issue to Microsoft. I have one luck of idb issue being fixed in ie10 after reported. It take a month just to ack issue. Chrome team ack issue in one day and very easy to create one. MS bug reporting is horribly lengthy. Another pending one is nested keyPath. I think multiEntry dont work too.

Comment: Yikes, sounds like I'll be be reworking my database to not use an array as a key.

Comment: Yeah, but you can encode array key to string as it does in Firefox IDB implementation or similarly in my lib https://bitbucket.org/ytkyaw/ydn-db/src/master/src/ydn/db/base/utils.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to get around this at the moment is to create a string out of the array and use it at the key as Kyaw mentioned.

```
request.onupgradeneeded = function(event) {
    event.target.result.createObjectStore("document", {keyPath: ['id']});
};
```

The id in the example would now have to be a concatenated string containing the title and version. Some like: `MyDoc_0`. You'd still store the title and version fields though so you can easily access them without have to split the id string.